# Copy matched pattern of line at the end of it

Tags: regex, bash, replace, find

I want to match a pattern from text and then append it at the end of line. In below case i want to match numbers and then paste it at the end of line. In case of matching two patterns want to have comma separated.
Basically i am looking how i can use the matching portion as variable.

I am looking to do it in Bash.

```
abc 123=
agdaf456ad
dfaf879:
abc123xyz12:
```

To

```
abc 123=123
agdaf456ad456
dfaf879:879
abc123xyz12:123,12
```

Comment: What if you have several "numbers"? Or do you always have just one? Is a "number" just a "sequence of digits"?

Comment: Right now my use case is several continuous numbers. But after your comment, i am curios to know if multiple patterns are matching in single line. How i can get both the patterns in different variables and how to use it? Like abc123xyz12: ->abc123xyz12:123 or abc123xyz12: ->abc123xyz12:123-12

Comment: Please update the question with actual requirements, and state the programming language you are using. What about [this PHP demo](http://ideone.com/w84JFB)?

Comment: Just realised just got an answer, now editing the question will invalidate that answer. That doesn't look right to be. Really sorry for creating confusion. I think now i can find out the solution for extended problem myself.

Comment: No, it is correct to precise the requirements. It is not a good idea to post duplicate questions. Please edit the question to include actual requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
(\d+)(.*)$
```

And replace with

```
$1$2$1
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dU5qB5/2)

**Example**

```
$replace = preg_replace("/(\d+)(.*)$/", "$1$2$1", "abc 123=");
echo $replace;
=> abc 123=123
```

Comment: @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９ Its a regex string replace function in php. When  I added the answer it had a tag saying so :/

Answer (score 0):

To get all sequences of digits in a given string, you can use a mere `\d+` regex, and then just implode the obtained result array and append it to the input string:

```
$str = "abc123xyz12:";
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $str, $m);
$append = implode(",", $m[0]);
echo $str . $append;
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/K1VAcY)